# Как считать текст из текстового файла в R в виде строки?

Tags: r

Здравствуйте!

Мне в **R** потребовалось записать текст из внешнего текстового файла в строку. Вроде это должна быть простая штука, но не смог найти готового рецепта, может, кто подскажет?

Пока пришлось обходиться такой конструкцией:

`mytext <- paste0(scan(file = "text.txt", what=character(),quiet = T), collapse = " ")`.

Команда 
`scan(file = "text.txt", what=character(),quiet = T)`
в принципе производит необходимое чтение из файла, но создает вектор слов (происходит разбиение по пробелам), а требуется именно строка, поэтому, дополнительно приходится склеивать этот вектор, используя `paste0`, чтоб восстановить исходный текст. В принципе, у `scan` есть аргумент `sep`, казалось бы, установи `sep=""` и всё, но результат такой же, как и без `sep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileName <- 'foo.txt'
readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

Из ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string

Comment: Получилось, благодарю!

Answer (score -1):

```
dt <- readLines("file.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает, во-первых, появляется сообщение:
Не Warning message:
In readLines("text_cd2.txt", encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on 'file.txt'

Во-вторых, строка хоть и при этом создается, но с русскими буквами в ней - беда: отображаются их 16-е коды. Поэтому, использую решение, предложенное @Ogurtsov.